# How to use Add Object To Json in robot Framework

Tags: python, json, robotframework

I have a JSON object :

```
[{'creationDatetime': '2022-07-01T15:03:45.928Z', 'eventIds': ['ff7f9780-f94e-11ec-93a8'], 'id': 1, 'info': 'API name : {RetrieveData}, Input : {Undefined}', 'status': 'CANCELED', 'system': 'UPDATE', 'type': 'POST', 'updateDatetime': '2022-07-01T15:03:45.928Z'}]
```

And I want to add a comment to it but I don't know how to use the Robot Framework Add Object To JSON.
I tried this :

```
     ${response_json}=   Add Object To Json    ${response_json}    $.   comment=Auto Test Modification
```

But I am getting an error.

The object comment along with its value should be added to the JSON object

Answer (score 0):

It would've been really helpful if you have said what is actually the error you're getting, instead of - guessing, it was something along the lines you are not passing an object, or there is no argument "comment" to that keyword.

The thing is - that `Add Object To Json` expects as a 3rd argument an object (that will be appended), but with "comment=Auto Test Modification" you're setting its arguments "comment" (which it doesn’t have) to that value.

The "fix" is simple - declare the dictionary you want appended, and pass that:

```
${new object}=    Create Dictionary    comment 
   Auto Test Modification

${response_json}=   Add Object To Json    ${response_json}    $.   ${new object}
```